# How to search comma separated words in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I want to list candidates count those having the keyskills (for eg: want to list candidate with keyskills like CSS or HTML or CSS5).
have a Candidate table and a KeySkill AND CandidateKeySkills table.

Keyskills added is stored in keyskills table with attribute name. In candidate_key_skills table candidate_id and keyskill_id are stored.

My model relation for candidate

```
candidate 
 has_many :candidate_key_skills, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :key_skills, through: :candidate_key_skills
end

class CandidateKeySkill < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :candidate
  belongs_to :key_skill
end

class KeySkill < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :candidate
  has_many :candidate_key_skills
  has_many :candidates, through: :candidate_key_skills 
end
```

I gets the candidate count in viewpage like this, but the SQL is wrong in keyskill name search part.

```
<% @candidates.each do |candidate| %>
      <% @c_skill_name = candidate.key_skills.map{|key| key.name}.join(",") %>
      <% @keyskills = Candidate.joins(:key_skills,:candidate_key_skills).includes({candidate: [:rate_card, :category, :company, :city, :key_skills]}).where('key_skills.name like ?',"#{@c_skill_name}") %>
      <% count = @keyskills.count %><%end %>
```

SQL in terminal

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `candidates` 
INNER JOIN `candidate_key_skills` ON `candidate_key_skills`.`candidate_id` = `candidates`.`id` 
INNER JOIN `key_skills` ON `key_skills`.`id` = `candidate_key_skills`.`key_skill_id` 
INNER JOIN `candidate_key_skills` `candidate_key_skills_candidates` ON `candidate_key_skills_candidates`.`candidate_id` = `candidates`.`id` 
WHERE (key_skills.name like 'css,css5,html')
```

it does list count of candidate with these keyskills.

Comment: Why are you not just using `candidate.key_skills` for this? It seems you're going around the houses to get the result of simply using that.

Comment: lot of issues in the way you are approaching this. You may want to give more details about the relation b/w candidate and key-skill in your system. Also, `like` query doesn't work that way. You might be looking for `IN` (on db level).

Comment: i just wanted to get like this "@c_skill_name = "css","css5","html" " instead of "@c_skill_name = "css,css5,html"

Comment: @SRack actually i shortened my query. actually query is like this. " Candidate.joins(:key_skills,:candidate_key_skills).includes({candidate: [:rate_card, :category, :company, :city, :key_skills]}).where('key_skills.name like ?',"#{@c_skill_name}") "

Comment: `@c_skill_name = "css","css5","html"` is likely not doing what you think it is.

Comment: i modified all details. please see

Comment: I'm quite sure that the sql query you posted does not in fact work. It should crash with a syntax error. Also, does your key_skills table __really__ contain comma-separated lists of values in its field `name`? This is terrible for querying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strange, because it seems that you can use just value of `candidate` from the `candidate.key_skills.map{|key| key.name}.join(",")` line.

But if you still need to implement such query,  you need to use `IN` expression:

```
Candidate.joins(:key_skills).where('key_skills.name IN (?)', @c_skill_name.split(','))
```

Or even simplier:

```
Candidate.joins(:key_skills).where(key_skills: { id: candidate.key_skills_ids })
```

Comment: First join, then split? Is it not easier to not do anything? :)

Comment: Thank you. Really feeling happy. Actually for a particular candidate i want to do this. So i tried with a different way.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I don't understand why this search is needed at all, because he has `candidate` at the beginning. Oh, maybe it is needed to find all similar candidates?

Comment: @zanadto: yeah, looks like "find similar"

Comment: I still maintain this will produce the same result as calling `candidate.key_skills` and is a complete waste of time.